# C# Looping through textboxes in a GroupBox

Tags: c#

I have a few textboxes inside a groupbox, I want to loop through them and add strings from List (array).

I've tried that:

```
foreach (var textBox in Controls.OfType<GroupBox>().SelectMany(groupBox1 => groupBox1.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()))
                   {
                       textBox.Text = List[counter];
                       counter++;
                   }
```

But it doesn't work for me, nothing happens.

Comment: You might need to add some more context to this - such as where you are adding textboxes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way:  It assumes there is more than one type of control in the group box.   If there are only textboxes, you can simplify it.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int Counter = 0;

    foreach (Control control in groupBox1.Controls)
    {
        TextBox textBox = control as TextBox;

        if (textBox != null)
            textBox.Text = Counter++.ToString();   
    }
}
```

Comment: Works now. But I can't get it to work with List. it says out of index. I'm trying to insert List[i] into each of the textboxes

Comment: It sounds like `counter` is going outside the number if items in what ever `List` is.  If there are three items in List and you try to access item number four.....fail.

Comment: I see. any ideas? I'm really lost

Comment: You would have to show the code concerning `List`.   Since this is a new problem, it may be appropriate to start a new question (unless it's really simple).

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
foreach(var groupBox in Controls.OfType<GroupBox>()) {
     foreach(var textBox in groupBox.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()) { 
    // Do Something 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this one.

```
foreach (TextBox txt in Controls.OfType<GroupBox>().SelectMany(g=>g.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()).ToList())
        {
            //Write your logic here
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner approach is

```
foreach(Control control in groupBox1.Controls)
{
    // Check if the object is indeed what we need
    if(!(control is TextBox))
        continue;

    // "Cast" the object to a TextBox
    TextBox textBox = control as TextBox;

    // Do your thing with the textboxes
}
```